# Conditional ARG in Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile

I'm trying to conditionally install vim in my docker container if I pass an optional ARG - say something like DEVBUILD. I can't find any documentation on how to use something like IF in a Dockerfile. Something like this:

```
FROM node:8
if $DEVBUILD {
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get --assume-yes install vim
}
```

Is this possible, and if so, where can find a reference on the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. When docker builds image it uses standard shell.

`Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM node:8
ARG DEVBUILD
RUN if [ "x$DEVBUILD" != "x" ]; then apt-get update && apt-get --assume-yes install vim; fi
```

If you define variable `DEVBUILD` like, for example, `DEVBUILD=true`:

```
docker build . --no-cache --build-arg DEVBUILD=true
```

actions under if statement will be executed.