# How to write conditional statement in Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile, environment

I tried to build a Docker image which runs Django with the following command:

```
python3 manager.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But the Docker image also needs to run on Windows which uses "python" instead of "python3".

I wonder if we can use a conditional statement to detect which Python command is on current OS.

I found this: [Conditional ARG in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775351/conditional-arg-in-dockerfile)

```
FROM node:8
ARG DEVBUILD
RUN if [ "x$DEVBUILD" != "x" ]; then apt-get update && apt-get --assume-yes install vim; fi
```

But I am not sure which argument about Python version is used on Windows and Linux.

Comment: The Docker image command is inside the container. Are you using different base images in the same file? I’d just have two dockerfiles, one for each base image.

Comment: The python on the current OS will not affect the Docker image -- that's part of the point of Docker :) If the Docker image has `python3`, then you can use `python3`. It will work on Linux and Windows.